# Augmented Reality library support React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, cross-platform, augmented-reality

I'm planning to develop a campus navigation mobile application combine Augmented Reality technology for my academic project. I decide to use React Native for develop a cross-platform mobile application (IOS and android). I am totally new in React Native and AR. Here are my questions.

1) Any AR libraries are fully support React Native? And able to work properly in Android and IOS? (I found few AR SDK that support Android and IOS, but I am not sure whether support React Native)

2) React VR builds on the React Native framework. Is it means React VR can be used to achieve my goal(AR navigation)?

3) Can anyone share their experience in React Native and AR? Then I will have a clear way to get started.

Comment: Did you ever find any libraries that would help you get started?

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this question (hope I'm not too late), but my company has released a React Native AR platform called Viro AR: https://viromedia.com/viroar/

To answer your questions:

1. It fully integrates with React Native in that you include the Viro component within your React Native code and use it concurrently with React Native to add 2D UI on top of AR. Currently it only supports ARKit for iOS, but ARCore for Android is coming soon (although ARCore is still in a developer preview state, so it's not ready for consumers).
2. React VR builds on top of React Native, but it won't give you AR Navigation in its current state because it lacks the 6DOF tracking that AR frameworks/libraries give you. Although, if you're also interested in  VR, Viro also supports VR w/ React Native too (Gear, Cardboard iOS/Android and Daydream Support): https://viromedia.com/virovr/
3. We built our ARKit-enabled app, Figment AR, using our AR platform as well as React Native for the 2D UI on top of it (think the buttons and list view and the preview screen). You can find that app right now on the Apple App Store: https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1270018902

So yeah, try out our platform and let us know if it works for you. Here are a few links:

- Documentation: http://docs.viromedia.com/
- Sample Code: https://github.com/viromedia/viro
- Issues/Support: https://github.com/viromedia/viro/issues & https://viromedia.com/contact-1/